# Street Fighter 2 - Guile's Handcuffs?

Tags: street-fighter-ii

I vaguely recall reading once, many moons ago, about a bug in SF2 that was referred to as "Guile's Handcuffs" or something similar. I've never been able to dig anything up about it. Does that ring a bell for any of you old arcade diehards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There you go:

[Guile's Handcuffs](http://old.jasongordon.com/static/sf2/guile.html).

> **Description**: Guile does the motion for throwing the opponent over his shoulder. Instead of being thrown, the enemy freezes close to Guile, with a "hurt" expression on their face. The computer or the second player is powerless (they cannot move). When Guile moves (or jumps) the frozen enemy follows. You must un-handcuff the opponent before the round ends. If you do not, at the end of the round, Guile will either brush his hair (if you win) or look away in agony (if you lose). After that, the game will hang indefinately until reset.
>
> **Why do this move**: This is another fun move to do. Not only does it look really cool, but its the glitch that looks the most wrong. Be aware that it can really annoy the person you are playing against, and they could become angry.
>
> **How to handcuff**: Though its not required, its easiest to do this move when the enemy is dizzy. Charge down for two seconds (I prefer to charge down-forward). Then press up (as if you were doing a flash kick) and hit the strong and forward buttons, while trying to hit strong a spilt second before hitting forward. I think of it as using your fingers to "brush down" over strong and forward. Basically what you are doing is throwing your opponent with strong, and while in middle of the throw, you do a flash kick. When this move is done, you see all of the frames of Guile's strong throw, however instead of flying across the screen at the end of the throw, the enemy sticks to you.

Fascinating how a glitch can turn into legend!

Comment: Thanks for that. I can now safely forget something that has been bugging me for, oh, ~15 years!